How should this S Trap be setup to allow my sink to drain faster?
My kitchen sink has been draining slowly for a while now. I thought maybe something was clogging the S Trap, so I took it off but it was clear. I then went to reassemble the pipes, and after doing so, the sink drains extremely slow now. This is the setup:

Which pieces need to be adjusted exactly in order to get it to drain faster? Diagrams I've found online don't really look like my setup at all, so I don't know what needs to be adjusted at all.

that is an S-trap

@jsotola I... didn't realize they were called different names

https://plumbjoe.com/p-trap-vs-s-trap/

With the trap off, stick a bucket under the sink drain (now open) and pour water down.  Does it drain fast?  If so, snake the part after the trap.  I.e. the vertical part going into the floor.
You also might get some improvement by adding an Air Admittance Valve (AAV) above the vertical drain.  However, I suspect an actual clog in this case.  It still may be worth adding the AAV to help avoid the next clog.
It's not strange for a clog to get worse after you take off a different pipe, so I wouldn't start by assuming it is something about the trap that has made it worse.  You've checked for a clog in the trap.  Now check other pipes.  The pipe between the sink and trap is short and easy to test, so do that first.  The drain pipe is harder, so do it second if necessary.

So, randomly, it seems to be draining better. I took a powerful flash light i have and shined it up against the pvc, and i can clearly see in the bend that leads to the straight down part that something is there.  Either me messing with it unblocked it enough, or it managed to clear enough open.  I might try clearing that piece some more.  I assumed i made the issue worse because I had the p trap elevation messed up, but that doesn't appear to be the case anymore

As for thr part from the sink drain to the p trap, it's clear. I was able to push a screw driver up it and out through the sink drain and it seems clear.

@mdfst13 that's an S-trap

The primary issue with your drain is that it is an S trap as @jsotola has pointed  out. S traps are prohibited by code in the US and there's a good reason for it. The suction of water draining out of an S trap will often drain the trap of it's water seal allowing sewer gas to leak into your home.

The reason you probably haven't been getting the smell of sewer gas is because of the slow drain issue. Once you solve it by clearing the pipes it will become an issue.
There are ways to change the configuration so it's a P trap instead of an S trap as a DIY even with the vertical drain. However, it requires venting and a few additional PVC pieces.
After you solve your flow problem (or before) as outlined in the above answers, post it as a separate question here on SE.

My house was built in the 1950s, so I assume this design has been in use in my house since then or at least while s traps were still allowed. And I guess that means I am grandfathered in.  It does occasionally have a faint sewer gas smell my sink, but rarely. It especially smelt when I took the trap apart!

Got it! Even if it;s grandfathered it's not a question of the code police coming to get you - It's about breathing sewer gas.

Right, i don't see anyone coming to yell at me anytime soon. But regardless it seems fixed for now. I should update this post to say s-trap instead. I cannot create the tag though.

So in my case, the s-trap as pointed out in comments I think was clogged. I shined a light against the PVC and could see some sort of blockage:

While I did not attempt to unclog it, I believe  I happened to unintentionally unclog it enough when I took it apart, as it now drains much faster again. It also doesn't smell, so for now, I am not going to attempt anything further.

How it works:
The water has to first fill up the p-trap, then it has to go high enough to overcome the second uphill and that slows it down.
Use two L-type connectors and a straight piece between them to replace, to lower the height of the second hill, allowing the water to flow faster.
